# Change location of sort arrow in DataGrid Header

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I began to work with DataGrid in WPF and i have a little problem.

I want to let the user re-ordering the column and it's working but i can't find the way to move the location of the sort arrow icon on the right side the header itself and not in the top of it. (look at the picture)

I think it's something simple but i can't find the solution.

[Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mlQ9.jpg)

Thank you for your help.